# samehead attibute in Graphviz python

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I'm trying to make the edges that share the same manager merge with each other. however, when I set the parameters for the attribute it doesn't apply to the org chart created using the code.

G.add_edge(manager, name, penwidth=.5, color="#2C3539", arrowhead="none", ltail=manager, samehead=name)
I'm using the above code to merge the edges together, please tell me if there is an issue with it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the graph-level attribute **concentrate** ( https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/concentrate/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, 
I have tried to incorporate it into this code I created but it did not seem to work, here is the line of code I've written : 
G = pgv.AGraph( rankdir="TB", splines="ortho",concentrate=True)
I'm struggling to find the issue why it does not apply the changes to my graph. thank you